# The driver detected a controller error on \Device\Harddisk0\DR0

Tags: hard-drive

What does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your drive controller or drive itself is having trouble. You better double check your backups. If it's a hard disk, try running a drive diagnostic tool from the manufacturer or run one of the drive utilities from the Ultimate Boot CD (google for it) to see if the drive itself is throwing any errors.